# create_product() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_id'

Tags: python, django

I m trying to use related object but i keep getting this error
create_product() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_id'
I have been trying to figure out how to fix the error 
Here is my views

```
def create_product(request, category_id):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        category_product = category.song_set.all()
        for s in category_product:
            if s.name == form.cleaned_data.get("song_title"):
                context = {
                    'category': category,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'You already added that song',
                }
                return render(request, 'shop/product/product_create.html', 

    context)
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            product.category = category
            product.save()
            return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'category': category})
        context = {
            'category': category,
            'form': form,
        }
        return render(request, 'shop/product/product_create.html', context)
```

I m trying to use related object but i keep getting this error
create_product() missing 1 required positional argument: 'category_id'
I have been trying to figure out how to fix the error 
Here is my views

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='category_created')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='product')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, db_index=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='users/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
    available = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

here is my urls for my views

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^category-create/$', views.category, name='category'),
    url(r'^product-create/$', views.create_product, name='create_product'),
    url(r'^category-detail/$', views.category_detail, name='category_detail'),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your create_product view contains 2 arguments, you need to include the 2nd one - category_id to you url as well.

In your urls.py change category_product url to:

```
url(r'^product-create/(?P<category_id>\d+)$', views.create_product, name='create_product'),
```

To make a link to this view from your template you need:

- `<a href= "{% url 'product:create_product' category_id=category.pk %}"> </a>.`
- create "product" namespace in your project root urls, by including
  product urls there. Like this:

  `from .product.urls import urlpatterns as product_urls

   url(r'^products/', include(product_urls, namespace='product')),`

Comment: how do I link to this url because I m getting no reverse match

Comment: replied above in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Edit your `urls.py`,

```
url(r'^product-create/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.create_product, name='create_product'),
```